# First order RL RC question

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I have problem with a question. Can someone help me with the solution? Thanks

[image: image of question]

Comment: Welcome :-) For homework (or at least homework-sounding) questions like this, you need to show your own effort and research first (click the "edit" link below your question, add your research and analysis into the question, and make it clear *exactly* where you are stuck). Failure to show your own work, research and analysis might lead to the question being quickly closed. Also, don't be surprised if you get hints and socratic questions, leading you to your own discoveries, rather than someone handing you the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Juamo. What is your specific problem with the task at hand? What have you tried? What did not work? What were you expecting, and what surprised you?
Please, edit your question with more details and the community will help you more willingly.

Answer (score 3):

Start working. Do not expect numerous ready to use solutions because they will very likely collect downvotes.

The capacitor has had time to get charged since minus eternity. You should be able to calculate how much there's voltage at t=0.

The capacitor is discharged to a resistor network which can reduced to one resistor when seen from capacitor's perspective. Find the discharging law from certain initial capacitor voltage when there's only one resistor load.

Calculate from discharging law by using voltage division rules Vo and Io as functions of time.

The question wants "total dissipated power" in the rightmost resistor. That can be presented as a function of time. I guess your teacher expects total dissipated energy, so you must integrate the power from t=0 to plus eternity or deduce the energy from the available energy and dissipation power distribution in the network.